# System.UnexpectedException: Script-thrown exception on HTTP callout

Tags: apex, callout, unexpectedexception

I'm trying to create an Apex callout and running into the following error message:

> System.UnexpectedException: Script-thrown exception

My analysis shows that

- `System.UnexpectedException` is not catchable in Apex.
- There are some reports of exceptions with “Script-thrown exception” message by other users, but the exception type in those cases happen to be System.CalloutException. [[1]](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001JitQQAS&title=script-thrown-exception-in-apex-callouts)
- The only reported case of a `System.UnexpectedException` with the same message appears to be triggered by log level of Callouts. (Note: the recommended workaround did not solve the problem in our case.) [[2]](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000JX7TQAW&title=system-unexpectedexception-script-thrown-exception-encountered-on-callout-when-callouts-log-level-is-finer-or-higher)

This is the code that causes the error:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:AmazonConnectAPI/contact/start-recording');
req.setMethod('POST');
String body = String.format(
  '\'{\'"ContactId": "{0}","InitialContactId": "{1}","InstanceId": "{2}","VoiceRecordingConfiguration": \'{\'"VoiceRecordingTrack": "{3}"\'}\'\'}\'',
  new List<String>{
    contactId,
    initialContactId,
    instanceId,
    voiceRecordingTrack
  }
);
if (body != '') {
  req.setBody(body);
}
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);
```

Other notable facts:

- The HTTP callout is made to a Named Credential called AmazonConnectAPI
- AmazonConnectAPI is configured for "https://connect.us-east-1.amazonaws.com“
- The authentication method of the Named Credential is Named Principal with protocol "AWS Signature Version 4"
- The authentication method uses the credentials for an IAM user with a full-access managed policy to Amazon Connect.
- The formatting of the body is correct. There is no syntax error.
- The error comes from this line `HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);`

Answer (score 7):

I was having some issues with my Named Credential (Named Principal) AWS Signature Version 4 and found some resolutions for the below error:

```
HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);
System.UnexpectedException: Script-thrown exception
```

#### 1. Named Credential Name

Double check your 'callout:Named_Credential' in Apex matches the Named Credential API 'Name'.

No brainer, but it got me for a few hours.

#### 2. URL Encoded Endpoint

Make sure to escape any URL reserved characters: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/url-encoding.

```
String endpoint = 'callout:Named_Credential/contactId/start=2021-02-10Thh:mm:ss.msm-00:00';
```

Should probably be:

```
String endpoint = 'callout:Named_Credential/contactId/start%3D2021-02-10Thh%3Amm%3Ass.msm-00%3A00';
```

No brainer, but it got me for a few more hours.

#### 3. Escaping Curly Braces in String.format()

I just ran this in Dev Console for your body and got the below:

```
System.debug((Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(String.format(
  '\'{\'"ContactId": "{0}","InitialContactId": "{1}","InstanceId": "{2}","VoiceRecordingConfiguration": \'{\'"VoiceRecordingTrack": "{3}"\'}\'\'}\'',
  new List<String>{
    'contactId',
    'initialContactId',
    'instanceId',
    'voiceRecordingTrack'
  }
)));

15:46:47:008 FATAL_ERROR System.JSONException: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1, column:171]
```

Changing the last few escaped curly braces from `"{3}"\'}\'\'}\'',` to `"{3}"\'}\'}',` got me a correct string

```
System.debug((Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(String.format(
  '\'{\'"ContactId": "{0}","InitialContactId": "{1}","InstanceId": "{2}","VoiceRecordingConfiguration": \'{\'"VoiceRecordingTrack": "{3}"\'}\'}',
  new List<String>{
    'contactId',
    'initialContactId',
    'instanceId',
    'voiceRecordingTrack'
  }
)));

15:40:31:006 USER_DEBUG [45]|DEBUG|{ContactId=contactId, InitialContactId=initialContactId, InstanceId=instanceId, VoiceRecordingConfiguration={VoiceRecordingTrack=voiceRecordingTrack}}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

To add to "1. Named Credential Name", this exception may also happen when a callout references named credentials that are included into a package **with a namespace**. Even if APEX code is included into the same package.

When it happens, the callout works in a Development org that has the same namespace as the package with the named credentials, but it throws "System.UnexpectedException: Script-thrown exception" when deployed to an org with a different namespace. So you'll just need to add package namespace to the callout.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:<namespace>__<Named_Credentials_Name>/some-path');
```